# Visualize joint probability distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

Consider the joint distribution function $p(x,y)=p(x) p(y|x)$

$p(x)$ corresponds to the density of a standard normal random variable, whereas $p(y|x)$ is given by $ \frac{1}{2} \delta(y-x)+ \frac{1}{2} \delta(y+x)$

The joint distribution looks like a cross in  $\mathbb{R^2}$, where the mass of the standard normal r.v. is located. How can I derive that by my given densities. For fixed $x$ the density of the standard normal is only scaled by $\frac{1}{2} $ for $y=|x|$. Where does then the rotation come from?

Comment: What is $\delta$, Dirac-delta function? If so, then remember that the Dirac-delta function is non-zero iff its argument is zero. Thus $p(y|x)$ is non-zero iff $y-x=0$ or $y+x=0$. These represent two straight lines in $\Bbb R^2$ and that's where $p(x,y)$ is non-zero.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri: Yes it is.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri: Perfect. So the mass is located along $y=x$ and $y=-x$.

Comment: @ShubhamJohn: How do I see on which side of these axis the standard normal has its mass?

Comment: I mean my density p(x,y) lies above for example $y=x$ with density 1/2 p(x)?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, are you trying to find $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^yp(x,y)~dx~dy$?

Comment: I mean p(x,y) has for example the form of 0.5 times the density of the standard normal r.v.   along the axis $y=x$

Comment: Because for y=x the density p(x) is multiplied by 1/2. Did I get that right?

Comment: What is the definition of Delta function given to you? The one I know takes $\infty$ when its argument is zero. You seem to be taking it as $1$.

Comment: Sorry I mixed something up. Yes it is $\infty$ when its argument is zero. Then I do not know exactly how p(x,y) looks like ?  How would you describe it.

Comment: Yes I thougt it would be one.

Comment: I would describe it only being non-zero on the two lines. You may be able say something about the marginal distribution of $Y$, as $f_Y(y)=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left[ p(x)\delta(y-x)+p(x)\delta(y+x)\right]dx=(1/2)[p(y)+p(-y)]$ where $p(x)$ is the PDF of $x$ (assumed to be a continuous function). But I am afraid not much else can be said about $p(x,y)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. So we cannot say p(x,y) is the density of two standardnormal r.v. distributed along y=x and y=-x

Comment: No, not really. It looks like even $Y$ is standard normal though.

Comment: Why? because of $f_y(x)= p(y)+ p(-y)$

Comment: Because $X$ is standard normal, so $p(y)=p(-y)$ due to symmetricity of the standard normal PDF, giving $f_Y(y)=p(y)$

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me a lot:)